# Elasticsearch: Do I need to index '_id' filed specifically?

Tags: elasticsearch

Looks like _id field is automatically mapped to [_uid](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-uid-field.html) by the Elasticsearch.

I have below query to get a document by passing document's _id

```
query: {
    match: {
      _id: myDocumentId
    }
  }
```

Should I specify indexing for _id field to make above query work fast or is it taken care by using _uid filed internally?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
GET /<index_name>/<type_name>/<myDocumentId>
```

Comment: Do you think there is any difference in performance in this request verse the   query I mentioned above? I am using [parent-child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html) mapping and my query is to get a child. I can't make GET request mentioned by you as it requires parent ID to be passed.

Comment: You don't have the parent available? Normally the GET request is faster than query.